# Synonym for rare occurrence but with negative connotation

Tags: synonyms, connotation

What are some synonyms for 'rare' or 'unusual' that have a negative connotation. For instance:

Enron's collapse was *unusual*, as the massive financial trickery ultimately bankrupted millions of investors.

What could replace 'unusual'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **Aberrant** may be my top choice, perhaps merely on account of it containing 'err', in this context. Others that may be appropriate depending on the emotion related would be:

**Strange**

**Unimaginable**

**Unthinkable**

Answer (score 0):

**Abnormal**
*Adj*: *Deviating from what is normal or usual, typically in a way that is undesirable or worrying.*

or perhaps:

**Pernicious**
*Adj*: *Having a harmful effect, especially in a gradual or subtle way.*

Comment: abnormal is closer, but I feel the connotation is not strong enough

Answer (score 0):

**Catastrophic**: While Enron's collapse was certainly bad, *catastrophic* might be a bit over-blown, depending on what point the writer is trying to make.

**Devastating**

**Calamitous**

**Ruinous** and **disastrous** may be slightly weaker than *catastrophic* and *devastating*.

While all these possibilities do not explicitly mean "rare", I think most people understand that disastrous events are rare by their very nature.